# As part of calling WCF as REST Service one of the Property of Type Dictionary is not getting serialized

Tags: json, rest, wcf, serialization

I have exposed calling WCF as Rest Service; I am able to call that specific Web Service with complex object. But one of the Property which is of type Dictionary is not getting serialized and becomes empty when it comes to WCF. I have provided more details in the code.

InFieldValuePair is dictonary

JSON Request :

```
{  
   "Requests":[  
      {  
         "AppRuleGroup":{  
            "AppId":0,
            "AppName":"XXX",
            "SubGroupId":0,
            "SubGroupName":"Corporates - Investment Grade",
            "GroupId":0,
            "GroupName":"Workflow",
            "ModuleId":0,
            "ModuleName":"Trading",
            "RulesLastUpdatedBy":null,
            "EvalRules":[  

            ]
         },
         "InputRequests":[  
            {  
               "Guid":"8592080a-6236-4b37-91b5-48c8a988950b",
               "InFieldValuePair":{  
                  "CurrentStatus":"Counter1",
                  "Direction":"Out"
               }
            }
         ],
         "Guid":"a0f0fba0-bf3b-4d3d-adc8-416b5448b3df"
      }
   ]
}
```

ABOUT

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Task<List<RuleEvaluationResponse2>> Evaluate2(List<RuleEvaluationRequest2> Requests);
```

Expected Result is dictionary object should be populdated

Answer (score 0):

First, please ensure that the property of the object has been decorated by **[DataContract]/[DataMember]**.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts
Besides, if the T has contained other object, in order to ensure the serialization and deserialization works properly, we should consider using [KnownType] attribute.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types
We could use IExtensibleDataObject interface to handle situations where server and client data contracts are inconsistent, and unserialized members are properly serialized.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject?view=netframework-4.8
At last, when Data Items are too many. Please consider using the MaxItemsInObjectGraph property.
https://thinksimpleshirin.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/increasing-maxitemsinobjectgraph-wcf/
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.